# ARMA-GARCH, invertibility, stationarity and insignificance

Tags: forecasting, arima, garch, volatility-forecasting

[image]

I am trying to forecast volatility out-of-sample using ARCH, GARCH, GJR and EGARCH. I used AIC to identify the ARMA and ARCH order and decided to stick with (1,1) for GARCH-type models. However, I have situation where my mean equation is either insignificant and/or non-invertible and non-stationary. The insignificance does not worry me too much, but I think the non-invertibility/non-stationarity will affect my forecast results out-of-sample. Should I remove the mean equation in the models where this happens? If no then how would this affect my forecast results out-of-sample?

Comment: +1 because I find the idea of removing the mean equation to be thought provoking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that nonstationarity and noninvertibility are the two more serious concerns when it comes to forecasting. If you have a nonstationary process where nonstationarity is due to the level of the series (the unconditional expectation is undefined or changing over time), you will have trouble forecasting the *level* of the series.

Is that important when you are actually interested in forecasting *volatility*? Yes, it is. You either define volatility as the magnitude of deviations from the conditional mean (the level) or from zero. In both cases nonstationarity in mean will cause you trouble.

> Should I remove the mean equation in the models where this happens?

Removing the mean equation will not solve the problem. In fact, you cannot remove the mean equation. A GARCH model specifies the conditional distribution of the time series, and that by definition specifies the conditional mean (unless it does not exist). In a GARCH(r,s) model for a time series $y_t$,

\begin{aligned}
y_t &= \mu_t + u_t, \\
u_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 u_{t-1}^2 + \dotsc + \alpha_s u_{t-s}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \dotsc + \beta_r \sigma_{t-r}^2. \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.d(0,1), \\
\end{aligned}

you have the element $\mu_t$. It can be zero, it can be something more complicated, but it is there, it cannot just be removed. And it specifies the conditional mean of the distribution of $y_t$, the latter being $y_t \sim D(\mu_t,\sigma_t^2)$. (It has to do with the properties of a random variable. Ignoring some property of a distribution, such as the mean, does not make it disappear.)

What I suggest is trying to see why the series appears to be nonstationary and address that (by adjusting for a deterministic or a stochastic trend, a structural change or the like). Then you will have a solid ground for your volatility forecasting.

> If no then how would this affect my forecast results out-of-sample?

If the conditional mean model is well specified and estimated well (e.g. the true process is explosive like $y_t = 1.1 y_{t-1} + u_t$ and it is estimated as such), your forecasts of the conditional mean should be fine. On the other hand, if there is, say, a neglected structural change, then the model will be misspecified and the forecasts will likely be poor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I think I haven't expressed myself right. When I talk about the mean equation I talk about the ARIMA(3,3) which I estimated first. Basically I estimated an ARIMA(3,3) checked for ARCH effects and then estimated and ARIMA(3,3)+GARCH(1,1). Obviouslt I can drop the arima and estimate: $$ r_t = \mu +\varepsilon_t $$ and the GARCH. If I drop the ARIMA however I need to drop it from all models, right?

Comment: @Alex, You are welcome! Technically it does not matter whether you estimate the mean and variance equations simultaneously or stagewise -- the mean equation is implicitly there, even if it is just a constant. Now if you want to compare ARCH to GARCH, GJR-GARCH and EGARCH, it would make sense to have the same mean equation, thus also to "drop" it from all models rather than just one or two of them.